# UNICODE_STRING is null or not?

Tags: c, windows, unicode, unicode-string

How to check if buffer of UNICODE_STRING structure is null or not ?
Its crashing while accessing buffer value, if null, but when i m checking it against null it return true.

```
if ( &struct.name.Buffer ){  --------------> this is returning true.
     name = wcscmp(
              (const wchar_t*)struct.name.Buffer,  --------------> crashing code.
              (const wchar_t*)localName);   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply do `if ( struct.name.Buffer )`. The ampersand gives you the address of the pointer `Buffer`, but not its value.

Answer (score 0):

check address inside the pointer struct.name.Buffer is a valid one or not